# Matlab y^2 = x^2 + 1 plot. (The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.)

Tags: matlab, function, plot, 2d

```
%Clear memory
clear;
%Number of points
N = 10000;
%Preallocate memory
x = zeros(1,N);
y1 = zeros(1,N);
x = -5 + (5+5)*rand(1,N);
y1^2 = x^2 + 1;
plot(x,y1), grid on;
```

I get the following error:

```
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

How can I plot this first on x,y axis, then on x^2 and y^2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Matlab is not a symbolic equation solver.  If you want to plot the solutions to `y^2 = x^2 + 1`, you'll need to find a way to express that as a function (or a set of parametric functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is ["multi-valued"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function). If you solve for `y1`, you'll have a solution in terms of +/- a square root. Therefore, you'll have to break your function into two and plot each branch. Some may also suggest using [`ezplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html), which is convenient, but not as flexible:

```
ezplot('y1^2 = x^2 + 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer gives the solution using ezplot which is an acceptable way of doing it. I want to throw in mine which aims to correct yours:

```
%Clear memory
clear;
%Number of points
N = 10000;

x = -5:0.01:5; %This creates a vector from -5 to 5 with an interval of 0.01.
y1 = sqrt(x.^2 + 1); %Since you want to solve the equation y^2=x^2+1, one of the solution is the positive root of x^2+1 and the other is the negative.
plot(x,y1); %Plots positive root
hold on;
plot(x,-y1), grid on; %Plots negative root
```